# Does having a Pakistani visa on my passport make it more difficult to get an American visa?

Tags: visas, usa, pakistan

I am an Indian Citizen planning to travel to Pakistan on a business visa. Once I have the Pakistani visa on my passport, will it be more difficult for me to get a visa to the USA? I intend to travel to the USA roughly six months after my travel to Pakistan.

Comment: Why not just apply for the US visa first?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That's actually an excellent point! But they might now allow Visa applications so early

Answer (score 9):

I don't have a source which can help, but I do have experience. My father has traveled to Pakistan as an Indian Citizen several times and still holds a B1/B2 Visa for the United States. He has traveled to the United States twice.

Expect being asked questions about your past travel. As long as your intentions for travel on both ends are/were fair and completely valid I wouldn't expect any kind of issues.

Similar to your situation, his travels for also quite near in time with each other. He also travels a fair amount to Bangladesh (more than 5 times until now). Several visits were interspersed in between without any issues.